# Custom button click not working in android

Tags: android

I made a custom button control in android with one left image, right arrow image and textview in middle. I want to make the right arrow image in the button down arrow while clicking it. For that i had written the following in custom button class

```
public class ButtonWithTwoImagesAndOneText extends LinearLayout{
private ImageView _image, _arrow;
private TextView _text;
private View _viewupper, _viewlower, _viewlowersmall;

public ButtonWithTwoImagesAndOneText(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs, 0);
    Init(context);  


    RelativeLayout nameLayout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lytcontrollayout);
    nameLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                _arrow.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowdown));
        }
    });
}
```

I used this button control in a layout like this.

```
<com.example.Controls.ButtonWithTwoImagesAndOneText
        android:id="@+id/btnaccountsettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </com.example.Controls.ButtonWithTwoImagesAndOneText>
```

and in the class of that layout i added button click for btnaccountsettings.

```
btnAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new RelativeLayout.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Account Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Now while running the app the arrow down is happening, but the toast is not working. Please help to solve this.

Comment: can you use the xml `android:onClick` succesfully?

Comment: You cannot register two onClickListener for a Button!

Comment: try to write this.setOnClickListener instead of nameLayout.setOnClickListener

Comment: @jvrodrigues is right. See answers

Comment: I tried this.OnClickListener and then the toast worked properly but the arrow down image not shown.

Comment: I tried android:onClick. I am stuck. I used android:onClick in custom button layout for the relative layout. Added OnClick function on the custom button class. But I have to define the click on another class. Error is showing to define the function.

Comment: In the custom control i have done, every time clicking on the button the down arrow image has to show. And i have to do different functionality for the button in the layout which uses this button. If i cannot register two onClicklistener how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout.OnClickListener should be View.OnClickListener.

```
btnAccountSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Account Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.I made this correction. The arrow down image showing working properly. Toast is also showing but only sometimes. I have a screen with 4 of this custom button, showing the toast with different messages. Actually i wanted this custom control used in different screens every time the arrow to be get down and after that i have to show different views.